# My.Settings no se guarda en vb.net

Tags: vb.net

tengo un problema simple, quiero guardar la configuración que yo quiero, ahora detallo lo quisiera guardar

```
My.Settings.Item("Servidor") = servidor
 My.Settings.Item("Usuario") = usuario
 My.Settings.Item("Contraseña") = password
 My.Settings.Item("Basededato") = basedatos
 My.Settings.Save()
```

despues cuando hago

```
My.Settings.Reload()
```

No me regresa sino que me da error, como si nunca hubiera guardado los ítems, podrían decirme por favor como es la manera correcta porque la documentación de Microsoft no esta claro. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tienes habilitado este check en la propiedades del proyecto?
[image: mysettings]